# Xamarin Android: What is the correct way to Marshal a string from C# to a Unicode string in C++?

Tags: c#, android, c++, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am writing a Xamarin Android app and trying to also write a C++ native library that the Xamarin app needs to pass data to. I need to pass a Unicode string to the library, but I am getting some strange behavior when I try.

In my native shared library, I have the following code:

```
extern "C" void logANSI(const char* data) {
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "StringMarshaling", "ANSI data: %s", data);
}

extern "C" void logUnicode(const wchar_t* data) {
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "StringMarshaling", "Unicode data: %ls", data);
}
```

On the C# side, I have the following `DllImport` declarations:

```
[DllImport("StringMarshaling", EntryPoint = "logANSI", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
public static extern void LogANSI([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string data);

[DllImport("StringMarshaling", EntryPoint = "logUnicode", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void LogUnicode([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string data);
```

Then I have the following code in my Activity:

```
  StringMarshaling.LogANSI("12345");
  StringMarshaling.LogUnicode("12345");
```

In the log output, I see:

```
05-17 18:07:12.437  Unitech PA700 Info  8351  StringMarshaling  ANSI data: 12345
05-17 18:07:12.437  Unitech PA700 Info  8351  StringMarshaling  Unicode data: 1
```

How can I get the full string, and not just the first character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__android_log_print` accepts a `char *`, so:

Using this C/C++ function:

```
extern "C" void logUnicode(const wchar_t* data) {
    std::wstring fooStr = std::wstring(data);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "StringMarshaling", "Unicode data: %s", fooStr.c_str());
}
```

With this DllImport:

```
[DllImport("StringMarshaling", EntryPoint = "logUnicode", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void LogUnicode(string data);
```

Calling:

```
StringMarshaling.LogUnicode("12345");
```

Will result in:

```
[StringMarshaling] Unicode data: 12345
```

Comment: According to the documentation, `__android_log_print`, "The details of formatting are the same as for printf(3)." printf should be able to handle wchar_t* strings using the `%ls` specifier. And you can see if you declare a local variable of wchar_t* and initialize it with a string literal, the log function handles it just fine. I think my problem has something to do with the fact that mono is expecting sizeof(wchar_t) to be 2, but it's actually 4 on Android.

Comment: @TheSned Actually on older API/NDKs `wchar_t` is 1, but yes in later NDK versions `wchar_t` is 4, `wchar_t` is very non-portable and in general should be avoided... Also all managed strings are UTF16-based, thus 2 bytes.

Comment: "`wchar_t` is very non-portable and in general should be avoided..." - this is the real answer to my question. :)